# My app is failing to deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

Below is the error I receive when I run git push heroku in the terminal. I am using the create-react-app Facebook boilerplate. If you need to see any more files please let me know!

https://gist.github.com/dsopel94/1681fc1214c02190f1bf3bbcdf4987c2

Comment: Can you tell us what is in your package.json?

Comment: @d-reaper https://gist.github.com/dsopel94/42490062c4b575a36b1fc5765998d6af

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a react project created with create-react-app that I have successfully deployed to heroku. I think the main issue with your setup is that heroku requires you to specify npm and node version in the package.json. You can do that by setting the "engines" property in your package.json.

```js
{
  "scipts" : ...,
  "proxy": ...,
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.1",
    "npm": "3.10.8"
  },
  //.. rest of package.json properties
}
```